# TypeScript interface property @version

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm writing an application on typescript and I faced the problem of object typing

I need to create a logstash object like this

```
{
  "message"    => "hello world",
  "@version"   => "1",
  "@timestamp" => "2014-04-22T23:03:14.111Z",
  "type"       => "stdin",
  "host"       => "hello.local"
}
```

but I don't understand how to create interface or type for properties with @ sign (@version, @timestamp).

For example:

```
const obj: ILogstashObjects = {
  "@version": "1",
  "@timestamp": "2014-04-22T23:03:14.111Z",
}
```

How should `ILogstashObjects` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a quoted identifier in the interface:

```
interface ILogstashObjects {
    "@version": string,
    "@timestamp": string,  
}
const obj: ILogstashObjects = {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-04-22T23:03:14.111Z",
}
```